# Algorithm for finding connected subgraph of a vertex weighted graph with a sum close to a given value

Tags: graph-algorithm, weighted

Given a vertex weighted graph G (depicted below), a vertex v from this graph and an integer value x, is there a known algorithm for finding a connected sub graph of G such that the target vertex is in this sub graph and the sum of weights of this sub graph is as close to x as possible? Moreover, if an exact match of x cannot be found, the algorithm should still return sub graphs closest to x as possible.

Some examples given the graph below:

v = F, x = 12. A,B,F,I and F,G,C,D are solutions.

v = C, x = 16. C,D,E,H is a solution.

[image: Vertex weighted simple graph.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding an solution looks like a variant of the Knapsack Problem to me, with the additional constraint that all items in the knapsack must form a connected graph.

One approach is to check all possible subgraphs containing `v` and searching for the maximum weight (up to your `x`):

You could use some kind of greedy algorithm, starting with node `v` and then adding one adjacent node after another, keeping track of the total subgraph weight. if you reach `x`, you are finished, if overshoot `x`, you must backtrack and select other nodes for your subgraph. During the whole algorithm, you keep track of your "best" subgraph, so if no exact solution is found in the end, you still have your best approximation.

You can choose the order of the nodes to add to your subgraph by utilizing a heuristic, e.g. Best Fit, but this only affects the run time, not the quality of your results..

Comment: I agree that it could be either a Knapsack Problem or the Subset Sum problem where we are restricted to a particular search problem restricted by the root vertex and paths from it.